# R converts factor into number when using sprintf

Tags: r, printing, casting, printf

I came across a weird casting situation and would appreciate if someone could explain to me what is going on.

I have a variable (a cell in a data frame as):

```
> missing_features[i,][j]
   aircraft_company_country
18           United Kingdom
```

The class of the variable is:

```
> sapply(missing_features[i,][j], class)
aircraft_company_country 
                "factor"
```

Somewhere in my script, the character column was converted in factor. When I try to print it using print and sprintf, it displays :

```
> print( missing_features[i,][j])

   aircraft_company_country
18           United Kingdom
> sprintf("%s",  missing_features[i,][j])
[1] "56"
```

A way to make sprintf print the right value is:

```
> sprintf("%s", lapply( missing_features[i,][j], as.character))
[1] "United Kingdom"
```

What is going on?

Comment: It must be because of the coercion of 'factor' to 'numeric' class. The values are the numeric levels.  Looks like you solved by converting to 'character' class.

Comment: Check `help(sprintf)`.  The `...` argument states *values to be passed into fmt. Only logical, integer, real and character vectors are supported, but some coercion will be done: see the ‘Details’ section.*

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `data.frame` to the `sprintf` function, which is not really supported. You should extract a single column to format with `sprintf` using `[[` instead of `[`, as shown in the following example.

```
> missing_features <- data.frame(aircraft_company_country = c("United States", "United Kingdom"), foo = 1:2)
> i <- 2
> j <- 1
> str(missing_features[i,][j])
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ aircraft_company_country: Factor w/ 2 levels "United Kingdom",..: 1
> str(missing_features[i,][[j]])
 Factor w/ 2 levels "United Kingdom",..: 1
> sprintf("%s", missing_features[i,][j])
[1] "1"
> sprintf("%s", missing_features[i,][[j]])
[1] "United Kingdom"
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.

Comment: Im so sorry! It must have been a mistake!

Comment: Actually, I don't know why it is -1. When I try to add one point, stackoverflow tells me I can not change the publicly displayed scores.

Comment: @user844924 No worries, I was just curious. You may not have been the one who down voted.